# Unable to download Visual Source Safe Upgrade Tool for Team Foundation Server from Marketplace

Tags: tfs, visual-sourcesafe, visual-sourcesafe-2005

I have been trying to upgrade my Visual SourceSafe to Team Foundation Server using the upgrade tool from the visual studio marketplace: Visual Source Safe Upgrade Tool for Team Foundation Server. However, I am not able to download the tool from the marketplace. I tried searching but most guides/websites link it back to the market place. The link to the visual studio marketplace is below:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EdH-MSFT.VisualSourceSafeUpgradeToolforTeamFoundationServer

Is there anyway for me to get the upgrade tool other than from the marketplace?
Thank you!

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: nothing. The page just reload when i click on the download button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked and can download it without any error, just try to refresh the page or with another machine to download it.

Whatever, I have transported it to OneDrive for you, you can download it via this link : https://1drv.ms/u/s!Am7qD1NqycgBkVmMdB3j8pg0w4L6

And this article for your reference: [How To: Migrate Source Code to Team Foundation Server from Visual Source Safe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668969.aspx)